# Corrupted data exception when run gremlin script

Tags: janusgraph, gremlin-server

JanusGraph 0.3.2 + Scylla as storage.

> `gremlin>  g.V(24624).valueMap(true)
>   Invalid flag encountered in serialization: -96. Corrupted data.
>   Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
>   Display stack trace? [yN] 
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid flag encountered in serialization: -96. Corrupted data.
>           at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readObjectInternal(StandardSerializer.java:257)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readObject(StandardSerializer.java:238)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readPropertyValue(EdgeSerializer.java:205)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readPropertyValue(EdgeSerializer.java:195)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.parseRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:129)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.EdgeSerializer.readRelation(EdgeSerializer.java:73)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor.readRelation(RelationConstructor.java:70)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1.next(RelationConstructor.java:57)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.RelationConstructor$1.next(RelationConstructor.java:45)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.LimitAdjustingIterator.next(LimitAdjustingIterator.java:94)
>           at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:651)
>           at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
>           at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.nextInternal(ResultSetIterator.java:54)
>           at org.janusgraph.graphdb.query.ResultSetIterator.<init>(ResultSetIterator.java:44)`

Comment: How to fix this data issue, I can't even drop the vertex :(

Comment: can you add the little more detail, how this error occurred, what you are trying to solve?